# Strange error when trying to configure Snort

Tags: linux, installation, kali-linux, configure

I've been following this guide: https://medium.com/@koayyongcett/snort-installation-in-kali-linux-from-the-source-9a005558a2ea teaching how to install snort, as using the `apt-get install snort` command that the book im reading recommends doesn't work.

I can complete every single step except the last one. When putting in the command `./configure — enable-sourcefire && make && sudo make install` I get the error:

```
 "checking build system type ... Invalid configuration "-": machine "--unknown" not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash .config.sub -failed.
```

I've searched everywhere online for a solution but I cannot seem to find one.
If it helps, I am running the latest version of Kali on a Virtual Machine.
Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: In the second line: `error: /bin/bach`.  Should it be `/bin/bash`?

Comment: Ah yes my bad, bin/bash just edited it now

Comment: Can you elaborate why your ```apt-get install snort``` does not work? Can you post the whole error message? It looks like config.sub is not found. But it also looks like you're missing build tools.

Comment: So if i put in 'apt-get install snort' I get the following:

Comment: The error message for apt-get install is 'E: Unable to locate package snort'. For the configure command it is the message I put in the description. I don't know why I would be missing build tools, although perhaps my it was my anti-virus which was acting up during installation of the VM, although I havn't told it to take any action explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this through some searching online. Thanks to Moreaki for pointing me in the direction of Build tools. The solution on here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584144/unable-to-locate-package-snort was part of the solution. Then I needed to install libnettle4. After that snort works perfectly.